# php emailer doesnt work for different server name

Tags: php

I have a basic php emailer codes. I tried it on my personal site.It works very well.My site host is like ;

```
 $mail->Host =mail.mysite.com
```

And i tried it another site, and of course i change the other values that needed,it doesnt work and i get this error : language string failed to load :connect host .

Also this site have a host like this : ***.secureserver.com .    (not like mail.mysite.com)

I thought this error should about hosting and  called the host company,they told me everything is ok about host,the code is wrong.

I try to find a solution,i hope somebody help

```html
function mail_gonder($isim,$mesaj,$konu,$eposta)
{
 require_once("class.phpmailer.php");

 $mail = new PHPMailer();
 $mail->IsSMTP();
 $mail->Host = "*****.server.net"; 
 $mail->SMTPAuth = true;
 $mail->Username = "noreply@***.com"; 
 $mail->Password = "****"; 
 $mail->From = "noreply@****.com"; 
 $mail->Fromname =$isim; // 
 $mail->AddAddress($eposta,$konu); 
 $mail->Subject =$konu; 
 $mail->Body = $mesaj;

 if(!$mail->Send())
 {
    echo '<font color="#F62217"><b>Gönderim Hatası: ' . $mail->ErrorInfo . '</b></font>';
    exit;
 }
 
echo '<font color="#41A317"><b>Mesaj başarıyla gönderildi.</b></font>';
}
```

Comment: your from attribute must be the same as server name where server name is www.ABC.com from must be example@ABC.com

Comment: and if you state what those stars are for people can help you more easily(for example give a name to them)

Comment: @jackjop - I believe the OP is just trying to hide sensitive info in his question with the asterisks.

Comment: check this out http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9109261/language-string-failed-to-load-from-failedfrom-email-address

Comment: I meant to give other names like ABC , XYZ as I mentioned with '(for example give a name to them)' @j08691

Comment: @jackjop giving abcz or anything to them wouldn't help you in anyway. you can replace the * by whatever you want.

Comment: I simply asked to understand what *****(five stars) and ***(three stars) stands for. ?! to know whether or not they're same

Answer (score 1):

The fix for this is actually simple, set the language to this:

```
$mail = new PHPMailer();
$mail->SetLanguage("en", 'includes/phpMailer/language/');
```

Make sure the files you have are all local. Make sure you uploaded the files to your live webserver. Some servers are setup not to allow some type of connections to external resources. Uploading the files to your own server have been known to fix this.

Comment: Thank you ,but i dont understand one point : although it is the same code and i i just change the mail server, why i do see this error ? why I dont see the error in using previous mail ?

Comment: Exactly @AysuVural the server names are different which means the servers are different. And if you have an issue then both servers are not set up the same way. Each server is set up differently so they react different to the operations maybe due to security settings, mail service and many more. That's my understanding.