# PHPMailer - Language string failed to load - where does that execute?

Tags: php, phpmailer

First, this is not a duplicate of [Language string failed to load: from_failed[from_email_address]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9109261/language-string-failed-to-load-from-failedfrom-email-address). I have carefully studied that post and tried the suggestions, but I always get this error:

> Language string failed to load

**Important: I can get PHPMailer to work, that is not the problem.**

The problem is, for the occasional times when phpmailer fails because a user entered an incorrect password, or got the host wrong or something, I get that annoying error message from phpmailer. So, there is no need to give suggestions on how to get phpmailer to work successfully - I can always do that when the settings are right. What I'm asking is why do I get that pesky message when the execution fails, and how can I resolve it?

Here's what I have tried:

- `$mail->setLanguage("en", "PHPMailer/language/");`
- I verified the language path exists - I can see it.
- I located my `phpmailer.lang-en.php` (inside `PHPMailer/language/`) and opened it in Notepad - it all looks fine.
- I used Astrogrep to search the contents of my PHPMailer directory tree. The string "Language string failed to load" exists nowhere - and yet clearly PHPMailer is emitting that string when a mail send fails.
- I cracked open `class.phpmailer.php` and found the function `setLanguage()`, and placed `die("just testing");` as the top line of the function. I ran a test. It doesn't get called and it doesn't die.

If I could find where `phpmailer.lang-en.php` is being called or referenced, I could easily solve this problem, but I can't find it and can't find where that error string is being emitted. I can see it's being referenced inside `setLanguage()`, but that function isn't being called, apparently, so I'm baffled. In case it matters, I'm loading PHPMailer into my php script thusly: `require_once("PHPMailer/PHPMailerAutoload.php");`

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That message means that you’re using a very, very old, buggy, obsolete, and vulnerable version of PHPMailer. Update to the latest version.

Comment: I upgraded to latest and it's all good now. Thank you Synchro.